# How to create GMSA account via C#

Tags: c#, gmsa

I have tried to look for the c# code example to see how the AD service account is created but not much luck. Anyone can provide an example code for creating AD service account please?

I have tried UserPrincipal with $ at the end of the name but not much luck. Errors with Access Denied (Cant create under root MyDomain or under a CN)

```
// Domain Context to use specific LDAP path.
domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainContext.ConnectedServer, "CN=Managed Service Accounts,dc=mydomain");
UserPrincipal userAccount = new UserPrincipal(domainContext)
{
  DisplayName = userName,
  SamAccountName = $"{userName}$",
  Description = description
};
userAccount.Save();
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code above? Does anything happen? Is there any error?

Comment: When i try to run the above code, it errors with "Access is denied". Mostly because I cant create an account under "mydomain" directly or under the CN which is set up for MSAs.

Comment: Seems to be an authorization issue

Comment: Are you able to create the account using powershell? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj128431(v%3Dws.11)

Comment: I can create the accounts without any issues in powershell using new-adserviceaccount which maps the account under the CN=Managed Service Accounts. I wanted to find a native c# way of creating the account instead of calling powershell though.

Comment: Is the C# program running as the same user as you run as in powershell?

Comment: I am using the same account in both powershell and c#. I am not sure if UserPrincipal is the right way to go about creating an AD Service Account though.

Comment: Agree, it might be the wrong way. Sadly I don't know and I have not find any pages for creating ad service accounts in C# when googling

Comment: @MarcusLai did you happen to find a good C# solution? I am getting ready to go down this path and there is not much information.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution purely in c#. I have a powershell invoke that does that for me now, which seems to be the only solution at this time

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but I think I can answer it. You need to use the NetAddServiceAccount function through logoncli.dll.  I hadn't been able to get it to work in PowerShell, even with adding what I thought was an appropriate type shim, but I just came across a module that seems to work.

https://github.com/beatcracker/Powershell-Misc/blob/master/Use-ServiceAccount.ps1

The C# code for the type definition in that script should have everything you need to implement it for yourself.

Comment: Where does one find logoncli.dll ? Once found, how do you suggest its used in C# ?

Comment: Same place you find most other system libraries. Try system32.

You'll probably need to learn how to use win32 API calls in c#.  If you have to ask...